# Python BeautifulSoup Not Getting Correct Value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape movie data from https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&genres=comedy&explore=genres but when I try to scrape the movie runtime text I get an error saying get_text is not callable and that is because in some of the movies that I am scraping there is no runtime. How can I make my code skip the movies with no runtime?

```
source = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&genres=comedy&explore=genres')
source.raise_for_status()
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
    
comedy_movies = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "lister-item mode-advanced")

for movies in comedy_movies:
    #movie title
    movie_title = movies.find('div', class_ = 'lister-item-content').a.text
    #Parental Advisory
    advisory = movies.find('span', class_ = 'certificate') #figure out how to single out advisory-
    #Movie runtime
    runtime = movies.find('span', class_ = 'runtime') #figure out how to single out runtime
    #Movie Genre
    genre = movies.find('span', class_ = 'genre').get_text()
    #Movie Rating
    rating = movies.find('span', class_ = 'global-sprite rating-star imdb-rating') #Figure out how to single out ratings
    #MetaScore
    metascore = movies.find('div', class_ = 'inline-block ratings-metascore') #.span.text same here missing values
    #Movie Description
    description = movies.find('div', class_ = 'lister-item-content').p.text
    print(runtime)
```

Also when I try to scrape the descriptions. I am not getting the descriptions, I am getting another text with the same

and class. How can I fix these? I will appreciate it a lot if someone can help.[my code executed with runtime showing the None values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxWP3.png)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error you can simply first check wheteher `find` returned anything that [is not None](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-check-if-not-none), like

```py
runtime = movies.find('span', class_ = 'runtime')
if runtime is not None:
    runtime = runtime.text
```

As for ratings, you want the contents of the `<strong>` tag *next* to the `span` you were finding:

```py
rating = movies.find(
    'span', class_ = 'global-sprite rating-star imdb-rating'
).find_next('strong').text
```

and for description, you would need to look for the `p` tag with `class="text-muted"` *after* the `div` with `class="ratings-bar"`:

```py
rating = movies.find(
    'div', class_ = 'ratings-bar'
).find_next('p', class_ = 'text-muted').text
```

although this will `find` None [and then raise error] when ratings is missing...

You might have noticed by now that some data (description, rating, metascore and title) would need more than one `if...is not None` checks to avoid getting errors if  anything returns `None`, so it might be preferable [especially with nested elements] to [`select_one`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead. (If you are unfamiliar with css selectors, [check this for reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).)

Then, you would be able to get metascore as simply as:

```py
metascore = movies.select_one('div.inline-block.ratings-metascore span')
if metascore is not None:
    metascore = metascore.get_text()
```

In fact, you could define a dictionary with a selector for each piece of information you need and restructure your for-loop to something like

```py
selectorDict = {
    'movie_title': 'div.lister-item-content a', 
    'advisory': 'span.certificate',
    'runtime': 'span.runtime',
    'genre': 'span.genre',
    'rating': 'span.global-sprite.rating-star.imdb-rating~strong',
    'metascore': 'div.inline-block.ratings-metascore span',
    'description': 'div.lister-item-content p~p'
    #'description': 'div.ratings-bar~p.text-muted' 
    # ^--misses description when rating is missing
}

movieData = []
for movie in comedy_movies:
    mData = {}
    for k in selectorDict:
        dTag = movie.select_one(selectorDict[k])
        if dTag is not None:
            mData[k] = dTag.get_text(strip=True)
        else: mData[k] = None # OPTIONAL
    movieData.append(mData)
```

with this, you could easily explore the collected data at once; for example, as a pandas dataframe with

```py
# import pandas
pandas.DataFrame(movieData)
```

[As you might notice in the output below, some cells are blank (because value=`None`), but no errors would have been raised while the for-loop is running because of it.]

| index | movie_title | advisory | runtime | genre | rating | metascore | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Amsterdam | R | 134 min | Comedy, Drama, History | 6.2 | 48 | In the 1930s, three friends witness a murder, are framed for it, and uncover one of the most outrageous plots in American history. |
| 1 | Hocus Pocus 2 | PG | 103 min | Comedy, Family, Fantasy | 6.1 | 55 | Two young women accidentally bring back the Sanderson Sisters to modern day Salem and must figure out how to stop the child-hungry witches from wreaking havoc on the world. |
| 2 | Hocus Pocus | PG | 96 min | Comedy, Family, Fantasy | 6.9 | 43 | A teenage boy named Max and his little sister move to Salem, where he struggles to fit in before awakening a trio of diabolical witches that were executed in the 17th century. |
| 3 | The Super Mario Bros. Movie |  |  | Animation, Adventure, Comedy |  |  | A plumber named Mario travels through an underground labyrinth with his brother, Luigi, trying to save a captured princess. Feature film adaptation of the popular video game. |
| 4 | Bullet Train | R | 127 min | Action, Comedy, Thriller | 7.4 | 49 | Five assassins aboard a swiftly-moving bullet train to find out that their missions have something in common. |
| 5 | Spirited | PG-13 | 127 min | Comedy, Family, Musical |  |  | A musical version of Charles Dickens's story of a miserly misanthrope who is taken on a magical journey. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 47 | Scooby-Doo | PG | 86 min | Adventure, Comedy, Family | 5.2 | 35 | After an acrimonious break up, the Mystery Inc. gang are individually brought to an island resort to investigate strange goings on. |
| 48 | Casper | PG | 100 min | Comedy, Family, Fantasy | 6.1 | 49 | An afterlife therapist and his daughter meet a friendly young ghost when they move into a crumbling mansion in order to rid the premises of wicked spirits. |
| 49 | Ghostbusters | PG | 105 min | Action, Comedy, Fantasy | 7.8 | 71 | Three parapsychologists forced out of their university funding set up shop as a unique ghost removal service in New York City, attracting frightened yet skeptical customers. |